# Spring MVC - jquery-i18n-properties can not load messages properties

Tags: jquery, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a Spring MVC 4 application with AngularJs. My problem is that AngularJs does not support internationalization. I want to use jquery.i18n-properties, but I can not load messages_%s.properties.

I get this error message:
**GET http://localhost:8081/base/resources/i18n/messages.properties?_=1426936125703 404 (Not Found)
jquery.js:7845 GET http://localhost:8081/base/resources/i18n/messages_en.properties?_=1426936125704 404 (Not Found)**

application-context-config.xml:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/WEB-INF/resources/ directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="/resources/html/templates/index.html"/>

<!-- Saves a locale change using a cookie -->
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" />

<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
    id="messageSource" p:defaultEncoding="UTF-8"
    p:basenames="resources/i18n/messages"
    p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/security-context-config.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/persistence-context-config.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/application-context-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here is what actually loads the files:

```
app.service('i18n', function () {
var self = this;
this.setLanguage = function (language) {
    $.i18n.properties({
        name: 'messages',
        path: 'resources/i18n/',
        mode: 'map',
        language: language,
        callback: function () {
            self.language = language;
        }
    });
};
this.setLanguage('en');
```

});

I dont use JSP-s, I just work with HTML-s. Here is my file structure:

```
  src
  |_main
    |_webapp
      |_WEB-INF
        |_resources
          |_...
          |_html
            |_... here are my .html files
          |_i18n
            |_messages_en.proerties
          |_images
            |_...
          |_js
             |_...
```

I tried a lot of things to resolve this problem, but nothing worked. Could somebody help me please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you using AngularJS, I think the best way to apply i18n is using this lib: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

This handle alot of thing with i18n.

Answer (score 0):

Example from their [homepage](https://github.com/jquery-i18n-properties/jquery-i18n-properties/wiki):

Take as an example the following Messages.properties, Messages_pt.properties and Messages_pt_PT.properties:

**Messages.properties**

```
# This line is ignored by the plugin
msg_hello = Hello
msg_world = World
msg_complex = Good morning {0}!
```

**Messages_pt.properties**

```
# We only provide a translation for the 'msg_hello' key
msg_hello = Bom dia
```

**Messages_pt_PT.properties**

```
# We only provide a translation for the 'msg_hello' key
msg_hello = Olá
```

So, as you can see, this plugin loads **three files:** the default file (eg, **Messages.properties**) first and then locale specific files (Messages**_pt**.properties, then Messages**_pt_PT**.properties).